# JavaScript: How to redirect user to a page on the basis of selected item of "Datalist"

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

I have this datalist for example:

```
    <datalist id ="List_1">
     <option value="Page 1">
     <option value="Page 2">
    </datalist>

    <input type = "search" name = "search" list = "List_1">
```

How can I redirect the user to Page 1 if he select "Page 1" when he selects it in the list.
  Thanks in advance~ !

Comment: You'll need to listen for the keyup event on the `input` and see if the value matches "Page 1".  Give it a whirl and show us what you got, then we might be able to help some more.

Comment: @technophobia I just want to know what is the command to target the user to a specified link
I know  about retrieving the index that he has selected and calling the function using the event
But all what I need is just the command to target if he selected the first index then "the desired command" 
Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you really want a jump list and not a data list.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you really want a jump list and not a data list. But in any case , your listener should be something like this.

```
function(e){
    if (e.target.list.options[0]){
        /* location.href = ''; */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other comments a jump list might be more appropriate. Where will you redirect a user to when they enter something in the `input` that is not in the `datalist`?

If you want to make sure that the value is one of the options from the datalist you'll have to do an exra check:

```
document.querySelector("input[name='search']").addEventListener('input', function(e){
   var input = e.target,
       val = input.value;
       list = input.getAttribute('list'),
       options = document.querySelectorAll('#'+list + ' option');

    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var option = options[i];
        if(option.value === val) {
            // we have a match, go to the value url
            window.location.href = "http://example.com/" + val;
        }
    }

    // still here? no match found
    doSomethingElse();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following html combined with the javascript to redirect the page to the given link:

```
<datalist id="List_1">
   <option value="Page 1"></option>
   <option value="Page 2"></option>
</datalist>

<input type="search" name="search" list="List_1">

document.querySelector('input').oninput = function() {
   window.location.href = this.value;
};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The `input` event fires on each character input. As soon as you'd type one letter in the input box this would already open a page for that one letter. Doesn't seem like a good solution